# @font-face in a CakePHP Webapp (Not working across various browser types)

Tags: cakephp-2.0, font-face

@font-face seems quote straightforward to setup in my CSS, and yet, my defined font is not being used. This is in a CakePHP 2.2 webapp, and despite trying all sorts of CSS URL path combinations, external CSS -v- inline CSS and single quotes/no quotes/double quotes in the CSS; nothing's working.

Here's the CSS:

```
<style> 
@font-face {
    font-family:TerminatorTwo;
    src: url(../files/TerminatorTwo.ttf) format('truetype');
}

div {font-family: TerminatorTwo}
</style>
```

My app has the default CakePHP folder structure, so the CSS is in app/webroot/css and the font (just the .ttf) is in app/webroot/files

Instead of the div part in the CSS, I've tried inline style definition on a specific div. Didn't work. the code as seen doesn't work, and it doesn't work wherever I try adding quotes in the CSS, as I've seen in other examples elsewhere. All this has been trie din the latest versions of IE8 (yes, 8, yuck), Firefox and Chrome. Oh, and Chrome for Android.

I've messesd around with the path too, but to no avail.

Utterly frustrated. It's inherently so simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font file is probably not loaded due to an invalid path. It's better to use the [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) for in these cases, as relative paths are bound to get messed up in a Cake install. Use the `url()` method to point to the `files` directory.

```
@font-face {
  font-family:TerminatorTwo;
  src: url(<?php echo $this->Html->url('/files/TerminatorTwo.ttf'); ?>) format('truetype');
}
```

Cake will make sure the URL points to the `files` directory in `/app/webroot` at all times.

Alternatively you could ditch the inline CSS and use an external stylesheet to avoid the issue with correct paths in Cake. In that case, if the CSS file is in the `app/webroot/css` directory, you could use the `../files/TerminatorTwo.ttf` notation.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. The text I'm trying to display is there, but it's not in the special font at all. Doesn't work inline, or in a CSS file. (Tested this solution with my app both on Firefox and IE8) (i'm stuck with IE8, where IE is concerned...)

Comment: Could it be the actual font that's the problem? I've installed it on my own PC, and it works fine, in, say Word...but, I uploaded it at fontsquirrel, hoping to generate al lthe different font filetypes, but was told it was an invlaid file...But, yeah, works fine on my PC...

Comment: Right, I've accepted your answer, as it was correct. I changed to a different font and it worked fine. Thanks.